# Were the 2009 MBP's affected by the NVIDIA problem?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, gpu

I am considering purchasing a mid 2009 Macbook Pro - 13", 2.53 GHz.

However, someone advised me to beware of the NVIDIA graphics card problem they had in 'that time frame'. As I understand, the video would go out or flicker and in general make the machine hard to use.

After much google, it seems that the problem happened during the 2008 time frame - see [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts2377) and [here](http://totalpoop.com/apples-2008-macbook-pro-nvidia-graphics-card-recall.htm) and [here](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/03/08/have-a-macbook-pro-with-a-faulty-gpu-and-no-applecare-you-may-s/).

I can't seem to find a single case where a 2009 MBP failed due to the graphics card. Since I'm thinking about purchasing, I would like some confirmation that, indeed, **2009 13" Macbook Pros were NOT affected by the NVIDIA graphics problem.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2009 models do not have the affected chipset.

Apple publishes all repair extension and other "recall" type news at this page:

- http://www.apple.com/support/exchange_repair/

You can use a tool like the Wayback Machine from the Internet Archive to [look at the contents of that page back to at least 2007](http://web.archive.org/web/20090601000000%2a/http://www.apple.com/support/exchange_repair/) if you are curious if there was a program earlier and it's no longer on the main site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have a mid 2009 15" macbook pro and this is hard to type b/c my screen is full of horizontal flickering.  The problem has persisted for weeks now, and at the genius bar I was informed that this model is now an "antique", & that repairs (new logic board, since the graphics card is integrated) can no longer be done.